# Get names of checkbox inside input field via JS

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to get names of the checked boxes in the text input field below in this format :

> name1 , name2 , name3  :

```
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33"/> A 
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33"/> B
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E66" value="33"/> C

<input type="text" id="sku" name="SKU" placeholder="show names here"/>
```

Have tried multiple times but nothings working.

Comment: In the value or in the placeholder of the `input` ? Have you tried anything ? Where is your issue ?

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried (and explain your reasoning behind it, if not self-explanatory) in any case. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the checkbox's using `forEach` and put the checked one to an array and finally join them by `,` :

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');


// Function that will be called when anchor is clicked
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", checkboxClick);
});

function checkboxClick() {
  var checked_names = [];

  Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.checked) {
      checked_names.push(item.name);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('sku').value = checked_names.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" /> A
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="34" /> B
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E66" value="66" /> C

<input type="text" id="sku" name="SKU" placeholder="show names here" />
```

Comment: Not working properly - if i uncheck the checkbox, its name is not removed from the input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `map`, `filter` and `join` methods.

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
let input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

input.value = Array.from(checkbox)
  .filter(({checked}) => checked)
  .map(({name}) => name).join(' , ')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" checked name="E33" value="33"/> A 
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33"/> B
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" checked name="E66" value="33"/> C

<input type="text" id="sku" name="SKU" placeholder="show names here"/>
```

Comment: Jquery !== Javascript

Comment: @Sølve Tornøe Updated with pure js solution.

Comment: @NenadVracar not working , names for not removed from input if checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @Sali You just need to run it on event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cb = document.querySelectorAll('.iput');
var ip = document.getElementById('sku');
var val = [];
for(var i of cb){
i.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
var cind = val.indexOf(e.target.name);
if(cind === -1){
val.push(e.target.name)
}else{
val.splice(cind,1)
}
ip.value = val.join(",")
})
}
```

```html
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33"/> A 
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33"/> B
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E66" value="33"/> C

<input type="text" id="sku" name="SKU" placeholder="show names here"/>
```

Comment: Thanks its working but needed a pure JS solution ! Still thanks for your input !